# extract links from webpages which require interaction

Tags: linux, shell, wget, html, javascript

I'm trying to figure out how, from a linux shell, to extract the links from a webpage in which the links appear only after clicking a button on the webpage, for example the "Assets" in github. If I download the page with `wget`, it won't contain any link from the assets, i.e.

```
wget -O /dev/stdout "https://github.com/yuzu-emu/yuzu-mainline/releases/latest" 2>/dev/null | grep ".AppImage"
```

does not return the link.
More generally, several webpages contain elements that are shown only after interaction; how does one get the html with those elements revealed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your *specific* example, you would be better served by using the github API, rathern than trying to scrape the web page. E.g:

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/yuzu-emu/yuzu-mainline/releases/tags/mainline-0-1180
```

This will return a JSON blog with information about the release (including a list of assets) that you can parse using `jq` (or your favorite language with JSON support).

---

More generally, if you want to access content on a page that is updated dynamically via Javascript after the page loads, you're not going to be able to do that easily from the shell.

You would typically need something like [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/) or [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) that allow for programmatic control of browsers, and these tools generally require you work with a more capable language (Javascript, Python, etc).

Comment: that's very useful, thank you! In alternative I was using browsh in server mode, https://www.brow.sh/docs/in-browser-usage/ , but it's a dirty workaround